# Creating iddata object seems to shift data along time-axis

Tags: matlab, time-series, signal-processing

I am a total beginner using Matlab/Simulink and need to do some system analysis.
Since I need to test the analysis algorithm for different system and signal conditions
I decided to create a simplified, but suitable simulink model for data generation instead of doing several 'real' experiments.
This model is called in the `get_data()` function and the data is returned to variable `d` as expected.

Since I need to do estimate the transfer function of the given system I had to create a `iddata` object in order to provide the data
in a suitable datatype.
The time steps of the retrieved from simulink is stored in `data_time`, system's input and output data in `data_in` resp. `data_out`.
Those three variables are then passed to `iddata()` in order to create the iddata-object `data_measured` as needed for the
transfer function estimation. The snippet for this is as follows:

```
% get data from simulink simulation executed in get_data function
d = get_data();

% extract data into variables
data_time = d.time;
data_in = d.data(:, 1);
data_out = d.data(:, 2);

% generate a time-domain data object (sample time given from simulink's noise generation)
data_measured = iddata(data_out, data_in, 0.1);
```

In further coding and data analysis I discovered that the time data of the iddata-object `data_measured` is not the same as given in
`data_time` as

```
any(data_measured.sa == data_time)
```

prints `0` indicating that none of the elements are `1` and the given arrays are not the same.

Since the above call of `any()` did not raise any error about unequal matrix dimensions I decided to plot both `data_in` vs. its
corresponding time-data `data_time` and `data_measured.u` vs. `data_measured.sa` by using

```
subplot(3, 1, 1)
plot(data_time, data_in);
title('Data retrieved from simulink') 

subplot(3, 1, 2)
plot(data_measured.sa, data_measured.u);
title('Data as in iddata-object') 

subplot(3, 1, 3)
plot(data_time, data_in, data_measured.sa, data_measured.u);
title('Data comparison')
```

The plot is given below:

[image: plot]

As you can see, there is a shift between the two plots which IMHO should not be there.
This shift in time does not seem to start right at the beginng of the data since there is a small area before the signal rises which is not
noisy. However, simulink is adding noise to the complete signal as you can see from the plot given in the middle.

So all in all it seems like passing the data to the `iddata()` somehow cuts the data along the time-axis and inserts some additional data.
Where does that come from? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a while I found out that the problem was related to the ODE-solver in Simulink.

Simulink was set up to select an appropriate solver and its step size automatically. This lead to varying step sizes which kind of expanded my data when using a discrete sampling time in the `iddata()` command.

After choosing the desired ODE-solver manually and setting up a fixed step size everything works fine. The shift/delay does not occur anymore.